# prove that $ W=(W^\perp)^\perp$

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

Let $W$ be a subspace of an inner product space $V$. Show that, 
\begin{equation}
W=(W^\perp)^\perp
\end{equation}

I understand how this can work just not sure how to prove this mathematically. I know that $W^\perp=\big\{v\in V: \langle w,v \rangle=0 \space \forall \space w\in W \big\}$ but unsure what $(W^\perp)^\perp$ would be and how to use $(W^\perp)^\perp$ to prove that it is equal to $W$.

Comment: Hint: $(W^\perp)^\perp = \{ v \in V: \langle w,v\rangle = 0\  \forall w \in W^\perp \}$.  To show that two sets $W$ and $(W^\perp)^\perp$ are the same, show that they are subsets of each other.  That is, let $x \in W$.  Show that $x$ must be in $(W^\perp)^\perp$.  Likewise, let $y \in (W^\perp)^\perp$ and show that $y \in W$.

Comment: This is not true unless $W$ is closed. The right hand side is always closed, but the left hand side need not be.

Comment: Maybe there is a missing assumption of $V$ being finite dimensional?